# LUKS password randomly not working on boot

Tags: boot, password, luks, cryptsetup

I have an odd problem and I am not sure what the reason might be. Sometimes, randomly my encryption password is not accepted and I get the following error message while booting up my computer:

`cryptsetup failed, bad password or options?`

That means, sometimes and randomly I have to enter my password a few times, say 4-7 times and then eventually I see "successful". Other times it just works at the first try. In either case I am very sure that I don't enter the wrong password.

To narrow the problem down, I added a second password to a free LUKS slot. That password was: `hello`

Even with that password, I suffer the same situation. Sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't.

I can rule out caps lock because the problem happens on cold boot too. Also, the caps lock light is off so I am pretty sure caps lock is not the problem. But, what could be the problem? Or, how to narrow the problem down?

Setup:

-Ubuntu 21.10

-Samsung SSD

-LUKS full-disk-encryption as per Ubuntu's installation wizard

Thanks!

Comment: I don't have that issue, did you try with another keybord maybe?

Comment: No, I didn't try another keyboard. The computer is a laptop, so it's always the same keyboard.

Comment: That's exactly why you should try another keyboard.

Comment: What would be the reasoning behind trying another keyboard? I am writing extensively with my current keyboard. It doesn't seem to be faulty.

Comment: Trying a USB keyboard is a good suggestion. The rationale is that your laptop may have a key that sticks sometimes, and sends multiple keystrokes, but it may not happen consistently

Answer (score 0):

Try to run a memory test (aka `memtest86+`) from the GRUB boot menu to confirm that your memory is working correctly. If you have memory that was faulty, it could lead to strange behavior like this, basically because bits are being flipped randomly while stored in there. If the memory test shows errors, replace your system's RAM.